# Is it possible to use variable with toastController in Ionic or Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, toast

I want to present a toast message to the user with his first name that I have in a variable. Is it possible? If so, how?

I want to do something like that:

```
this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: "Welcome user.firstname" ,
  duration: 3000
}).present();
```

where `user.firstname` contains my user's firstname.

PS: The code above is not working, it shows the message "Welcome user.firstname"

Comment: Why not simply do `"Welcome " + user.firstname`?

Comment: You already have the answer. The `message` to be shown in the toast is a string. Just concatenate your string and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters to the toast

```
async toastCtrl(msg) {
  const toast = await this.toastController.create({
    message: msg,
    duration: 300
    });
  toast.present();
}
```

Call the function with a variable

```
this.toastCtrl('Welcome ' + user.firstname);
```

Comment: How does wrapping this in a function improve on simply doing `"Welcome " + user.firstname`?

Comment: Because you could use the toastController for different messages if needed

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
this.toastCtrl.create(
    { 
        message: "Welcome " + user.firstname, 
        duration: 3000 
    }
).present();
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot . My real difficulty was how to concatenate